# Нейронная сеть, выборка слов для токенов

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, keras

Я мог неправильно дать название "токены", поправьте, если что

У меня есть набор данных (около 5000 текстов в которых суммарно около 250000 слов). Так как я обучаю нейронную сеть, то мне надо переделать все эти слова в векторы. Перед сетью стоит задача классификации его в одну из 26и групп (классов). Сейчас я пользуюсь функцией tokenize() из Keras:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_x)  # train_x -- все слова
textSequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(_train_x)
inp = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(textSequences)
```

`inp` - то, что подаётся на вход нейронке

Но точность сети просто ужасно низкая:

```
    Train on 53464 samples, validate on 5941 samples
Epoch 1/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 42s 782us/step - loss: 2.8512 - acc: 0.1958 - val_loss: 5.3621 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 762us/step - loss: 2.3860 - acc: 0.3115 - val_loss: 6.3154 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 763us/step - loss: 2.0529 - acc: 0.4189 - val_loss: 6.9755 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 762us/step - loss: 1.8181 - acc: 0.4768 - val_loss: 7.4485 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 759us/step - loss: 1.6520 - acc: 0.5199 - val_loss: 7.8625 - val_acc: 6.7329e-04
Epoch 6/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 759us/step - loss: 1.5259 - acc: 0.5567 - val_loss: 8.1456 - val_acc: 0.0025
Epoch 7/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 763us/step - loss: 1.4228 - acc: 0.5860 - val_loss: 8.5147 - val_acc: 0.0047
Epoch 8/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 761us/step - loss: 1.3347 - acc: 0.6106 - val_loss: 8.7964 - val_acc: 0.0056
Epoch 9/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 766us/step - loss: 1.2589 - acc: 0.6320 - val_loss: 8.9138 - val_acc: 0.0069
Epoch 10/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 761us/step - loss: 1.1917 - acc: 0.6507 - val_loss: 9.1383 - val_acc: 0.0103
Epoch 11/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 767us/step - loss: 1.1308 - acc: 0.6668 - val_loss: 9.2275 - val_acc: 0.0118
Epoch 12/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 42s 782us/step - loss: 1.0755 - acc: 0.6832 - val_loss: 9.5163 - val_acc: 0.0130
Epoch 13/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 42s 787us/step - loss: 1.0250 - acc: 0.6969 - val_loss: 9.6945 - val_acc: 0.0123
Epoch 14/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 40s 756us/step - loss: 0.9772 - acc: 0.7095 - val_loss: 9.7978 - val_acc: 0.0123
Epoch 15/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 40s 751us/step - loss: 0.9337 - acc: 0.7233 - val_loss: 9.8795 - val_acc: 0.0130
Epoch 16/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 40s 756us/step - loss: 0.8935 - acc: 0.7352 - val_loss: 10.0735 - val_acc: 0.0151
Epoch 17/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 772us/step - loss: 0.8553 - acc: 0.7474 - val_loss: 10.2456 - val_acc: 0.0153
Epoch 18/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 40s 755us/step - loss: 0.8194 - acc: 0.7582 - val_loss: 10.3284 - val_acc: 0.0146
Epoch 19/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 40s 752us/step - loss: 0.7855 - acc: 0.7702 - val_loss: 10.4330 - val_acc: 0.0162
Epoch 20/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 774us/step - loss: 0.7552 - acc: 0.7798 - val_loss: 10.5150 - val_acc: 0.0131
Epoch 21/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 40s 753us/step - loss: 0.7255 - acc: 0.7900 - val_loss: 10.5869 - val_acc: 0.0155
Epoch 22/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 40s 750us/step - loss: 0.6977 - acc: 0.7978 - val_loss: 10.8555 - val_acc: 0.0130
Epoch 23/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 40s 750us/step - loss: 0.6724 - acc: 0.8073 - val_loss: 10.7549 - val_acc: 0.0155
Epoch 24/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 775us/step - loss: 0.6480 - acc: 0.8141 - val_loss: 10.9706 - val_acc: 0.0131
Epoch 25/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 40s 753us/step - loss: 0.6250 - acc: 0.8218 - val_loss: 11.0208 - val_acc: 0.0157
Epoch 26/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 41s 774us/step - loss: 0.6034 - acc: 0.8294 - val_loss: 11.0658 - val_acc: 0.0145
Epoch 27/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 40s 749us/step - loss: 0.5845 - acc: 0.8353 - val_loss: 11.1852 - val_acc: 0.0155
Epoch 28/100
53464/53464 [==============================] - 40s 751us/step - loss: 0.5661 - acc: 0.8398 - val_loss: 11.2610 - val_acc: 0.0133
Epoch 29/100
 4512/53464 [=>............................] - ETA: 35s - loss: 0.5074 - acc: 0.8579
```

Думаю, что:

1. Так как точность при обучении высокая, а при проверке - низкая, то сеть просто не учится всем словам, это так? Какая может быть еще причина?
2. val_loss растёт. Это значит, что нейросеть начинает учить хоть какие-то слова? Или что?

По этим двум пунктам я считаю, что 50К слов - слишком много. Но если я уменьшу их число (переменную `num_words`), то слова не из всех типов текстов могут туда попасть. Если я возьму самые популярные слова из каждого класса, то они могут вообще начать совпадать (например, слово "привет" может быть во всех сразу же, а мне нужна оригинальность)

В общем, всё слишком сложно для меня. Пожалуйста, помогите с этими вопросами

Comment: Вы можете выложить ваши данные на какой-нибудь файлообменник и привести код, который вы использовали для построения модели?

Comment: @MaxU, вот ссылка на colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aWuNHqY2D38XZthZX8gBj1UzyYDReJ9a

Comment: @MaxU, а вот на входной файлы (shelve формат) https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x9bc8wloc7plhfr/AAB99PxX487QOQ4l9kbYwP7pa?dl=0